# host subdomains files in firebase

Tags: firebase, subdomain, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I have a domain called **test.in**, I hosted it into firebase.
i also created a subdomain called **tryme**
Now i want to upload files for my **tryme** subdomain on firebase hosting.

I have directories like this
`root/test/public/index.html root/test/tryme/index.html`

I already connect my subdomain to firebase, Now how can i upload new file `tryme/index.html` on `tryme.test.in`

Where should i move my `tryme` folder that contain files for `tryme` subdomain?